# ui components and dataProvider file for a simple upload file functionality in your custom module

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

In my module there is a link for an import and then the user should arrive to something like this:
[image]

Where they are able to upload a file and then click the import file button and then that file updates some products.

I'm struggling with the ui_components and DataProvider files.

I don't even know if a DataProvider should be needed for something like this but if I don't include it in ui_components then it throws an error.

All of my import logic is done in an importFile.php that should get called by the submit_url.

ui_component/module_form.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">module_form.stores_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">module_form.stores_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">module_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="stores_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Module\Path\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">stores_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">file_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">file_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="module/path/importFile"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="stores_main">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="import">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">stores</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">module/file-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm not sure how `Module\Path\DataProvider` should look like. I thought there would be one created in the products module: `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\DataProvider` but there isn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataSource's `class` argument should be a reference to your module's DataProvider class.

This class doesn't have to do anything as long as you extend `\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider`. It should implement `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface` which the `AbstractDataProvider` does.

If you need to provide data to your form, then that class provides a mechanism for you to do that. Magento's standard approach appears to be to have a `getData()` method that returns nearly an array of data to be output in JSON along with the rest of your component's configuration.

Magento's example is that you would put your `DataProvider` in the `[YourNamespace]\[YourModule]\Ui\DataProvider` namespace (where [YourNamespace] and [YourModule] are placeholders for your module's name).